# LT Spice Project is taking too long

Tags: power, circuit-design, power-electronics, ltspice, pspice

I am trying to implement a simple LT Spice circuit; it takes extremely long a 50ms simulation isn't settling even at 5 seconds. Tried adjusting the internal capacitances of the component, the AUX has a demand of 36V, which seems to be the issue. Each part of the circuit is working seamlessly on its own, but when I am merging them, it seems to be an issue.[image]

PS I am new to LT Spice. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some general cheats you can try: alternative solver, 1 Megaohm resistor to ground from your floating voltage sources, tiny RC filter across switches and diodes.

Answer (score 2):

I am suspicious of V2,V3 and V7,V8 possibly being the wrong way around...

Generally one should spice small bits of doings, running a whole system seldom ends well because it just gets madly slow even if it converges at all.
I would loose most of the +-15V power stuff, one of each will be quite sufficient and will make the model much simpler.

I would also simplify the thing to answer whatever the question you want to ask, rather then trying to build an entire power supply.

Comment: Oh please, I literally begged them to let me lose this chaos of 15V throughout, apparently that is what makes it look like real life. xD

Comment: And also don't know the extreme love with LTSpice. They are glued.

Comment: @SubhransuSekharBhattacharya LtSpice is not actually bad, and is very common, for all that the UI is a bit weird. Given that those 15V rails are all perfect voltage sources (no series ESR, ESL) and no decoupling I fail to see how they make this look any more real, I would guess that academenture is involved somewhere?

Comment: yes, I am an undergrad doing an internship. I feel this platform has no place for newbies trying their best to learn smh. Unfortunate tbh.

Comment: @SubhransuSekharBhattacharya Meh, LtSpice has a GUI however rough, I learned spice typing in the netlists manually on a VT220 terminal (No graphics) and running the model as a batch job, then plotting the curves by hand on graph paper from the printout. It was only marginally quicker then just finding the poles and zeros by hand. There are LOTS of different tools out there all with different user interfaces, the interface is a detail, what matters is getting a feel for what spice is good at, where it needs a little help with convergence and where it sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the VCSW, it looks like you're after a simple, behavioural model, not a real-life case. Therefore `U1`, `U2`, and `U3` (+ sources) can be replaced by two voltage sources of fixed pulse-width (say `1 Vpk`), and you could try to help the simulation by using a better behaved `.model` for the VCSW: `.model sw sw ron=10m roff=10meg vt=0.5 vh=-0.5`.

If you'll also add `Rser=1...10m` to `V14` and the capacitors, and maybe even an `Rpar=10...100k` to the inductors, it would only help. And, while you're at it, you could simplify things some more by using the generic diode models by renaming them all to `D`, and using `.model d d ron=10m roff=10meg vfwd=0.45 vrev=1k epsilon=0.1 revepsilon=50m`.

Not lastly, it would do you, and everyone looking at your schematic, if you'd draw it in a more readable way. This last part is not a bad habit to form.

---

Looking more closely I see that the `.model` cards are wrong: you declared them for switches named `MSW` and `MYSW`, yet all of them have the default `SW`.

I also see `V13` having a bizarre value. On the one hand, if it's a regular voltage source, then that value is not allowed and LTspice should complain from the start, because it contains a time-variable, `V(in)`. On the other hand, if it's a behavioural source, then it's missing the `V=` in front of the expression (unless it's on a different, hidden line in its attributes), but then it's designator seems wrong (but LTspice can reinterpret that behind the scene).

So I've redrawn your schematic with these changes, and it works just fine:

[image: test]

Here is the source:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1420 816
WIRE 272 -96 208 -96
WIRE 416 -96 336 -96
WIRE 896 -96 832 -96
WIRE 1040 -96 960 -96
WIRE 128 0 32 0
WIRE 160 0 128 0
WIRE 208 0 208 -96
WIRE 208 0 160 0
WIRE 272 0 208 0
WIRE 416 0 416 -96
WIRE 416 0 352 0
WIRE 480 0 416 0
WIRE 608 0 560 0
WIRE 640 0 608 0
WIRE 688 0 640 0
WIRE 832 0 832 -96
WIRE 832 0 688 0
WIRE 896 0 832 0
WIRE 1040 0 1040 -96
WIRE 1040 0 976 0
WIRE 1104 0 1040 0
WIRE 1264 0 1168 0
WIRE 1296 0 1264 0
WIRE 1344 0 1296 0
WIRE 32 16 32 0
WIRE 128 16 128 0
WIRE 32 96 32 80
WIRE 32 96 -96 96
WIRE 688 96 688 0
WIRE 1344 96 1344 0
WIRE 208 112 208 0
WIRE 416 112 416 0
WIRE 608 112 608 0
WIRE 832 112 832 0
WIRE 1040 112 1040 0
WIRE 1264 112 1264 0
WIRE 128 176 128 80
WIRE 128 176 -96 176
WIRE 912 176 912 48
WIRE -96 208 -96 176
WIRE 32 208 32 96
WIRE 128 208 128 176
WIRE -96 288 -96 272
WIRE 32 288 32 272
WIRE 32 288 -96 288
WIRE 128 288 128 272
WIRE 128 288 32 288
WIRE 208 288 208 176
WIRE 208 288 128 288
WIRE 416 288 416 176
WIRE 416 288 208 288
WIRE 528 288 416 288
WIRE 608 288 608 176
WIRE 608 288 528 288
WIRE 688 288 688 176
WIRE 688 288 608 288
WIRE 832 288 832 176
WIRE 832 288 688 288
WIRE 912 288 912 256
WIRE 912 288 832 288
WIRE 1040 288 1040 192
WIRE 1040 288 912 288
WIRE 1264 288 1264 176
WIRE 1264 288 1040 288
WIRE 1344 288 1344 176
WIRE 1344 288 1264 288
WIRE 192 352 48 352
WIRE 288 352 288 48
WIRE 288 352 256 352
WIRE 192 384 128 384
WIRE 896 384 832 384
WIRE 1040 384 960 384
WIRE 48 432 48 352
WIRE 128 432 128 384
WIRE 832 480 832 384
WIRE 832 480 768 480
WIRE 896 480 832 480
WIRE 1040 480 1040 384
WIRE 1040 480 976 480
WIRE 1104 480 1040 480
WIRE 1264 480 1168 480
WIRE 1296 480 1264 480
WIRE 1344 480 1296 480
WIRE 1344 576 1344 480
WIRE 832 592 832 480
WIRE 1040 592 1040 480
WIRE 1264 592 1264 480
WIRE 912 656 912 528
WIRE 832 768 832 656
WIRE 912 768 912 736
WIRE 912 768 832 768
WIRE 1040 768 1040 672
WIRE 1040 768 912 768
WIRE 1136 768 1040 768
WIRE 1264 768 1264 656
WIRE 1264 768 1136 768
WIRE 1344 768 1344 656
WIRE 1344 768 1264 768
FLAG 336 48 0
FLAG 160 0 in
FLAG 128 512 0
FLAG 48 512 0
FLAG 640 0 aux
FLAG 960 48 0
FLAG 1296 0 1
FLAG 528 288 0
FLAG 960 528 0
FLAG 1296 480 2
FLAG 768 480 aux
FLAG 1136 768 0
SYMBOL voltage -96 80 R0
WINDOW 0 -41 10 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -159 -12 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value sin 0 90 50 rser=0.1
SYMBOL diode 48 80 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value rec
SYMBOL diode 144 80 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value rec
SYMBOL diode 48 272 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMATTR Value rec
SYMBOL diode 144 272 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMATTR Value rec
SYMBOL cap 192 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 100u
SYMBOL sw 368 0 M270
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMBOL diode 336 -112 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D5
SYMBOL voltage 128 416 R0
WINDOW 0 27 92 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -46 119 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value pulse 0 5 0 12u 12u 0 24u
SYMBOL Digital\\diffschmitt 192 304 R0
WINDOW 3 -9 114 Left 2
WINDOW 123 -13 135 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMATTR Value vt=0 vh=0
SYMATTR Value2 tau=1n tripdt=1n
SYMBOL bv 48 416 M0
WINDOW 3 36 41 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName B1
SYMATTR Value V=36/v(in)
SYMBOL ind 464 16 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 123 -41 63 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 320u
SYMATTR Value2 Rpar=10k
SYMBOL diode 432 176 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D6
SYMBOL cap 624 112 M0
WINDOW 123 24 78 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 12u
SYMATTR Value2 Rser=10m
SYMBOL res 672 80 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 52
SYMBOL cap 816 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 100u
SYMBOL sw 992 0 M270
SYMATTR InstName S2
SYMBOL diode 960 -112 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D7
SYMBOL ind 1024 96 R0
WINDOW 123 36 102 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L2
SYMATTR Value 352u
SYMATTR Value2 Rpar=10k
SYMBOL diode 1168 16 M270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D8
SYMBOL cap 1280 112 M0
WINDOW 123 24 78 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value 3u
SYMATTR Value2 Rser=10m
SYMBOL res 1328 80 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 153
SYMBOL voltage 912 160 R0
WINDOW 0 27 92 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -55 148 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value pulse 1 0 {2.93/5*24u} 10n 10n {2.07/5*24u} 24u
SYMBOL cap 816 592 R0
SYMATTR InstName C5
SYMATTR Value 100u
SYMBOL sw 992 480 M270
SYMATTR InstName S3
SYMBOL diode 960 368 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D9
SYMBOL diode 1168 496 M270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D10
SYMBOL cap 1280 592 M0
WINDOW 123 24 78 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName C6
SYMATTR Value 52u
SYMATTR Value2 Rser=10m
SYMBOL res 1328 560 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL voltage 912 640 R0
WINDOW 0 27 92 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -58 163 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value pulse 1 0 {1.2/10*24u} 10n 10n {3.8/5*24u} 24u
SYMBOL ind 1024 576 R0
WINDOW 123 36 102 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName L3
SYMATTR Value 75u
SYMATTR Value2 Rpar=10k
SYMBOL cap -80 208 M0
SYMATTR InstName C7
SYMATTR Value 1n rpar=1meg
TEXT -104 632 Left 2 !.model d d ron=1m roff=0.1g vfwd=0.45 vrev=100 epsilon=0.1 revepsilon=50m\n.model rec d ron=10m roff=0.1g vfwd=0.7 vrev=1k epsilon=0.1 revepsilon=50m\n.model sw sw ron=10m roff=0.1g vt=0.5 vh=-0.5
TEXT -96 752 Left 2 !.tran 1
```

Comment: I have successfully completed the circuit. Could you help me if the input voltage stands at 260V other conditions being same. Also I am confused regarding which opamp characteristics to choose.

Comment: @SubhransuSekharBhattacharya Your schematic shows a buck stage, followed by two buck-boost, no isolation from the mains, and virtually no control over the output, so I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, let alone why, or what for. You also mention something about "they" not letting you do something, so who are these and why can't "they" help you with this ...design?

Comment: They being my superior, who wants me to redesign an obsolete Power system that they have been using. I am interning with them, and I am in the waters as I have never used LT Spice before. And they have denied me help. Also f, or the 260V, I just care about the buck. Couldnt understand what u meant by no virtual control over the output, could u please elaborate and no I, can't use an isolated main, and I have to use rail voltage; that was literally the only constraints.

Comment: Oh, I have tried. No improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, SPICE does not converge well with Inductors, unless you chose an alternate "interpolation" algorithm.

Or you place non_derivative components (resistors) in parallel or in series.