# Cannot create an appropriate regulation

Tags: power-electronics, ltspice, spice, pspice, ngspice

I am trying to build a 260V input mains circuit for a 36V output and 25W Power. I have calculated the required Resistance, Capacitor, and Inductance, I have got the required results. However, I am required to **make a closed-loop PWM**. Could anybody please help? Thanks!
[image]
PS: I am very new to LT Spice and Power Electronics.

---

Also, I am posting my output. Please do take a look and let me know. Something that is not visible on the circuit is that I have used a 70 ohm Series resistance with the inductor.I am looking for making a closed loop PWM so that I dont have to use a constant Duty Cycle.
[image]

Comment: That 260 V sine source is delivering 260 V peak. Did you want 260 V rms? 'Not getting' is not a good problem description. What output ARE you getting? 0 V, 1 MV?

Comment: Sorry for that vague question I am getting 130uV. No I wanted 260 peak.

Comment: What becomes 130 uV? Aux? Vin? Is S1 conducting at all?

Comment: Yes S1 is conducting but please help me out with how to use the correct opamp..yes I need 36V on Vaux and its showing 130uV.

Comment: What is R2? 1n?

Comment: When you right click on U1, what op-amp have you chosen?

Comment: The op-amp chosen doesn't seem to make any difference LT1028A is my preference, though. Oh please ignore R2. That again isnt making any difference. I was simply falt testing.

Comment: Please reconsider the idea of building an un-isolated mains supply.

Comment: @ChrisStratton done...no difference

Comment: @Aaron so I am not too sure why but I used Vos as 500 when I was working with 90V instead of 260V and it seemed to have worked.

Comment: Why do `R2` and `C2` have those values? Why is there no control loop? Why is there no galvanic isolation? This seems related to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/523806/95619). Why did you choose this topology instead of another?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, please ignore those values as I was just testing...they don't create any difference to the output. Yes, they are related. This topology was suggested, again like I said new to LT Spice.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen also the solution you gave me for the last question didn't work for whatever reasons, and again, the requirement is 36V.

Comment: I have thoroughly gone through Buck and Boost circuit designing, but thank you for your suggestion. I am in the process.

Comment: I suggest opening the .asc file in a text editor and copy/pasting the text into a code block within your question.  That way we can troubleshoot the actual circuit instead of making assumptions based on a screenshot with limited information.  Regardless, the main thing that sticks out at me is V5 should be a B-source and not a V-source.

Comment: Can you post the `.tran` output plots for `Vin`, `Aux`, output of the `SW` and output of `U1`. Plot them on different graphs. Not in the same graph.

Comment: @SteKulov it is one seems to be a glitch. Ill post the code. Also we could used closed loop. But I seem to have worsened the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there will be some problem with the calculation. For this to work without regulation, two things must be met.

1- The duty cycle of the switch signal is fixed.

ON time = 36 x K

OFF time = (260-36) x K ;(K = constant)

2- A minimum of inductance is required for the current of the inductance to be continuous.
That is, it cannot be decreased to zero during the switch off time.Here we choose either inductance or frequency. One defines the other.
[image: egy]

[image: kettő]

The output capacitor only affects the ripple of the output signal. Its value is not critical.

I don't know where the 90 uH came from, it can't be ruled out in principle, but in practice it would require too high switching frequency.

Comment: I am allowed to use a regulation circuit but I cannot figure out the criterions.

Comment: I have figured out all the criterions but the average output doesnt meet the requirement as I have not been able to put in regulation. Thus I had to use the Duty cycle as a fixed value.

Comment: The 11V / us slew rate is likely to be very low here. Maybe a high speed comparator would be better than an operational amplifier.